# Temporal downsampling with FFMPEG

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video

My task is simple: I have some video `input.avi` that consists of `N` frames. I would like to **downsample** the video using **FFMPEG** with respect to the **temporal** dimension by a factor of `M` (e.g. `M=10`). `N` is not necessarily a multiple of `M`.

I want to do two things:

1. Keep every `M`-th frame (e.g. 0, `M`, `2M`...) and drop the other frames
2. Aggregate over `M` frames (i.e. non-overlapping windows of size `M`) by computing, for instance, the average in the RGB space (will probably produce some blurriness for large `M`)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think it is sufficiently clear: I want to subsample a video by only including every ```M```-th frame, where ```M``` is some arbitrary positive integer.

Comment: The **Bot** is correct... When you are giving few options it's unclear what you are asking. How do we suppose to know if dropping frame is better than averaging frames? I believe a better solution is applying "smart" temporal noise reduction (not simple averaging) and keep every M-th frame of the result (I don't know if FFmpeg supports it). I can't answer without seeing the input video.

Comment: OK. I see your point. But I would appreciate solutions to both problems, there doesn't need to be an analysis which of them is better.

Comment: Could you add some detail about what you've tried? Does it have to be ffmpeg (OpenCV or processing.org mighty be better fits)? Can you link to a sample input (so people can try solutions).